# How to show the latest commit time of the each branch when they are diverged in git?

Tags: git

When the local branch and the remote branch are diverged, `git status` whill report they are diverged. However, I would like to list the latest commit of the each branch so that I know which is the newest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collecting a list of all branches in a repository in a special format \[Git\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362007/collecting-a-list-of-all-branches-in-a-repository-in-a-special-format-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **git log --oneline** to see all the commits of your local repo, it shows head of your current local and head of your remote repo.

And if you also want to see the time of commit then you can use

```
 git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
```

and to see the graph of all the branches use

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

Comment: I prefer `log --graph --all --format="\"%h %d %cr %s\""`.